# Python venv pip is always outdated

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

Whenever I create a fresh Python 3.11 virtual environment using `venv`, the provided `pip` always prompts me to update to the latest version, even though my base version appears to be up to date

```bash
$ python3.11 -m pip --version
pip 23.0.1 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
$ python3.11 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate.fish
(venv) $ pip install requests
...
Successfully installed ...

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

Why doesn't the virtual environment have the newest release to begin with? Is there a way I can manually set it for future  virtual environments? I'd like to not have to deal with this slight inconvenience everytime I create a new virtual environment.

Comment: Have you updated your global pip?

Comment: Is your base pip current to clone off of?

Comment: @JonSG It was not, but even after updating my base the problem persists. I've updated my question to include that. I do have many python executables on my system, so perhaps `python3.11 -m venv venv` is not cloning the same `pip` that is referenced with `python3.11 -m pip`?

Comment: That surprises me.  You can almost certainly force the issue by `python -m venv venv --upgrade-deps` though

Answer (score 3):

The `venv` module uses the `ensurepip` module to install a hard-coded version of `pip` that is bundled with `ensurepip` itself. While `pip` is not part of the standard library, `ensurepip` is. It does this, I believe, for a couple of reasons:

1. You know exactly what version of `pip` will initially be installed fora given version of Python, no matter what machine you are using.
2. You can create a virtual environment without needing a network connection to download `pip` from PyPI or elsewhere.

You can see the wheel used to install `pip` by looking in the directory containing the `ensurepip` package.

```
>>> import pathlib, ensurepip
>>> list(pathlib.Path(ensurepip.__file__).parent.glob('*/pip*'))
[PosixPath('[...]/python3.9/ensurepip/_bundled/pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl')]
```

Comment: If you update this answer to include steps for a solution, I will likely accept it.

Comment: If you want a later version of `pip`, you already know what to do: you upgrade `pip` using `pip`. You can't force `venv` to install something other than what it is hard-coded to install.